# How do I trigger an event on text selection in the editor?

Tags: tinymce

I am looking to trigger an event when some text is selected in the editor. I have tried using getNodes, selectorChanged etc. but haven't had any luck yet.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

getNodes, selectorChanged, getContent